# Stack Overflow generating broken HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, design

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816910/how-do-i-add-more-than-one-row-with-zend-db/816945#816945) when I noticed that the font for the user information block was wrong. Checking the original source of the page, I found this (formatted just for you):

```
<!-- Suspect code starts here -->
    <p>Regarding returning auto-generated keys, I wouldn't bother.  Notice that if you use plain SQL (in the mysql CLI for example), and you insert multiple rows in a single INSERT statement, you can only get the last generated id value, not the id values for all rows inserted.  This is SQL behavior; it's true for any language or any framework.</p>
    <pre>
        <code>
            INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9);
            SELECT LAST_INSER
</div> <!-- **** Bad! **** -->
<!-- Suspect code ends here -->
<!-- Below are the post links (link, edit, flag) and the user information block -->
<table class="fw">
```

As you can see, the `div` element that I have marked closed off the post body `div` without first closing off the `code` or `pre` tag.

But, that's not all. Checking the original source of the answer (via the edit link), it would seem that Stack Overflow chopped off the final portion of markus' answer, including some of the code in the final code block.

If had to make a guess, I'd say that it would be the double dashes (`--`) in markus' code block. But, I don't think I should be editing his answer just to find out.

Comment: Can reproduce. I remember there was a bug that chopped off the end of longer answers. This post is old enough, so it may be the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very old bug that occurred in the process where posts are converted from Markdown to HTML. It's been fixed, but any posts saved by the broken renderer need to be (edited and) resaved to be fixed.

Comment: When editing for this sort of reason, how can I get around the restriction that prohibits edits that don't change more than a certain threshold of characters?

Comment: @peter you could improve something else in the post (is it *so perfect* that nothing else in it can be improved?) or flag for mod attention. 2k+ users can do a no-op bit-twiddle edit.